# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined Uncaught TypeError:?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to print the object name in the y has its key value but getting an error.
please help me...

this is my java script code

```
var object = {
    name: "venu",
    id: 99,
    age: 100,
    "x": [
        "balaji",
        22,
        11
    ],
    "y": {
        name: "balu",
        id: 55,
        age: 22
    }
};

var g = object.x;
for (var i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < g[i].y.length; k++) {
        console.log(g[i].y.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve in this code?

Comment: 1. There is no object with an property `y` in `object.x`/`g` 2. `object.y` would be an object and has no property `length`

Comment: JSON format is wrong, there is no property y in x.

Answer (score 0):

```
var object = {
name: "venu",
id: 99,
age: 100,
"x": [
    "balaji",
    22,
    11
],
/*>>>not inside the x>>>*/ "y": {
    name: "balu",
    id: 55,
    age: 22
}
};

var g = object.x;
for (var i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
for (var k = 0; k < g[i].y.length; k++) { //object.x.y.length is undefined as y is not something in x
    console.log(g[i].y.name);
}
}
```

Comment: Any reasonable explanation why?

Comment: i removed the double quoutes from the x and the y and i didn't get my answer

Comment: @balajiunnam Issue is not with quotes. Please refer @`Andreas`'s comment. That should be enough